# Python numpy array replacing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array which looks like this for example:

```
array([[ 1,  1,  2,  0,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10,  0,  0, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22,  0, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]])
```

I have another two arrays which are like:

```
array([[   0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0, 2891,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0, 2891]])
```

and

```
array([[  0,   0,   0, 643],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 643,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

What I want is to pick value 2891 from the 2nd array to the first array in the corresponding position and also 643 from the third array to the first array in the corresponding position so that the final array should look like this:

```
array([[   1,    1,    2,  643,    4],
       [   5,    6,    7,    8,    9],
       [  10, 2891,  643,   13,   14],
       [  15,   16,   17,   18,   19],
       [  20,   21,   22, 2891,   24],
       [  25,   26,   27,   28,   29],
       [  30,   31,   32,   33,   34],
       [  35,   36,   37,   38,   39],
       [  40,   41,   42,   43,   44],
       [  45,   46,   47,   48,   49]])
```

So far I have tried this command:

```
np.place(a,a<1, np.amax(b))
```

where `a` referred to the first array and `b` referred to the 2nd array. What it does it just replace all the 0 value with 2891 value. Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the indices where `y` and `z` are nonzero using the nonzero method:

```
In [9]: y.nonzero()
Out[9]: (array([2, 4]), array([1, 3]))

In [10]: z.nonzero()
Out[10]: (array([0, 2]), array([3, 2]))
```

You can select the associated values through [fancing indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/numpy/docs/numpy-docs/reference/arrays.indexing.rst/#arrays-indexing):

```
In [11]: y[y.nonzero()]
Out[11]: array([2891, 2891])
```

and you can assign these values to locations in `x` with

```
In [13]: x[y.nonzero()] = y[y.nonzero()]
```

---

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[ 1,  1,  2,  0,  4],
              [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
              [10,  0,  0, 13, 14],
              [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
              [20, 21, 22,  0, 24],
              [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
              [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
              [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
              [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
              [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]])

y = np.array([[   0,    0,    0,    0],
              [   0,    0,    0,    0],
              [   0, 2891,    0,    0],
              [   0,    0,    0,    0],
              [   0,    0,    0, 2891]])

z = np.array([[  0,   0,   0, 643],
              [  0,   0,   0,   0],
              [  0,   0, 643,   0],
              [  0,   0,   0,   0],
              [  0,   0,   0,   0]])

x[y.nonzero()] = y[y.nonzero()]
x[z.nonzero()] = z[z.nonzero()]
print(x)
```

yields

```
[[   1    1    2  643    4]
 [   5    6    7    8    9]
 [  10 2891  643   13   14]
 [  15   16   17   18   19]
 [  20   21   22 2891   24]
 [  25   26   27   28   29]
 [  30   31   32   33   34]
 [  35   36   37   38   39]
 [  40   41   42   43   44]
 [  45   46   47   48   49]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean select the max values from the second array and third array? If so, try followings:

Init Data:

```
In [48]: arr = array([[ 1,  1,  2,  0,  4],
   ....:    [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
   ....:    [10,  0,  0, 13, 14],
   ....:    [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
   ....:    [20, 21, 22,  0, 24],
   ....:    [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
   ....:    [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
   ....:    [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
   ....:    [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
   ....:    [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]])

In [49]: arr1 = array([[   0,    0,    0,    0],
   ....:    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
   ....:    [   0, 2891,    0,    0],
   ....:    [   0,    0,    0,    0],
   ....:    [   0,    0,    0, 2891]])

In [50]: arr2 = array([[  0,   0,   0, 643],
   ....:    [  0,   0,   0,   0],
   ....:    [  0,   0, 643,   0],
   ....:    [  0,   0,   0,   0],
   ....:    [  0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

Select and Replace:

```
In [51]: arr[arr1==arr1.max()] = arr1.max()

In [52]: arr[arr2==arr2.max()] = arr2.max()

In [53]: arr
Out[53]:
array([[   1,    1,    2,  643,    4],
       [   5,    6,    7,    8,    9],
       [  10, 2891,  643,   13,   14],
       [  15,   16,   17,   18,   19],
       [  20,   21,   22, 2891,   24],
       [  25,   26,   27,   28,   29],
       [  30,   31,   32,   33,   34],
       [  35,   36,   37,   38,   39],
       [  40,   41,   42,   43,   44],
       [  45,   46,   47,   48,   49]])
```

Comment: might be faster to store `arr1.max()` / `arr2.max`

Comment: thnax for your answer. I understood the explanation of 2nd answer thats why I accept that one. But yours working as well.

Comment: Be care there's a few differences between our answers. I select the max value and replace them While they select those non-zero and then replace them. If there're two kind of non-zero numbers in your second or third arrays, the output will be different.

Answer (score 0):

In numpy you can subscript arrays in strange ways. 1. with a boolean array 2. with indices

```
a1[a2 > 0] = a2[a2.nonzero()]
```